# Receive an Error from promise.js - Clone the HTML Object in IE11 using Javascript and html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, exception, clone, html2canvas

UPDATED - sorry

I'm working on a DC.js dashboard and I'm trying to provide a screenshot feature. Currently I develop a button that will called a DIV id that contains all the charts in it and convert the SVGs into Canvas so I can screenshot using the HTML2Canvas. Though during the process, I have to provide an inline style for the charts in order to make this works so I have to create a clone object that it wont make changes on the existing page. When I click on the button, I received this error on the console page in Developer Tool. The error is..

```
"Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Unable to get property 'removeAttribute' of undefined or null reference."
```

I have to work on IE11 so this is kind of challenging due to limitations. I did implement the promise.js because IE11 doesn't support promise feature.

Example:

```
<div id="masterContainer"> 
    ... 'all the html, svg, etc. elements  to create the charts'
</div>
```

In Javascript, I have a button that called the masterContainer and do its process.

```
function screenshot() {
  var getContainer = $('#masterContainer');  
  var cloneObject = getContainer.clone();  -- I want to clone this div object along with the elements inside it.

  elementsToCanvas(cloneObject);  -- This is a function where it takes that html object and convert all the svgs, ect. to canvas. Also takes the cloneObject and apply it to html2canvas;
}
```

I just want to create a clone object for that masterContainer without making changes on the existing page... THOUGH it works without cloning the object but that made changes on the existing page. Please help.

Comment: ">I tried using the .clone() but within that object, it does not have the .find function as part of it .." What does that supposed to mean?

Comment: Very sorry, Please view my updated question. I think the clone object works but I'm receiving an exception while processing the html2canvas

Comment: it seems to me, that you'll need to include a promise polyfill

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are asking here but `element.cloneNode` is supported in ie 11. However to clone all its children, you will need to provide an optional parameter, `true`, just make sure that you do not accidentally add it to the DOM and end up with duplicate ids.

```
function screenshot() {
  var clone = document.getElementById("masterContainer").cloneNode(true);

  elementsToCanvas(clone);
}
```

**Update:** Based on the exception that you paste, it seems to me that is has nothing to do with the clone but the fact that `Promise`s are NOT supported at ie11. Consider using a conditional [polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did apply promise.js and polyfill.js too. Also, just now, I just click on that polyfill link you provided and updated both js files but i receiving a syntax error on the top of the script where it says import. Any idea?

Comment: That is for server side, on browser side you need to use this script: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js

Comment: I have apply the es6-promise.auto.min.js file. When I click on the button, I didnt see the error but nothing happens when i used a clone object. though it did work when i used the existing object.

Comment: clone the entire html: `document.documentElement.cloneNode(true)`   and try to use this clone to see if it works. And please consider making a  fiddle. Because it is quite difficult for me to pin point what is exactly going on based on only your description.